# How can I calculate successive elements in a database using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Is there a way I can query the database to return only the elements that have happened successively (in time) according to a set variable?

Specifically, I need to find out how many times the user has won a game in a row. The games are stored in the database with an attribute win_loss (1 is win, 0 is loss).

I would like to see if the user has won 3 games in a row. Is there a way to do this in the database?

If not, what would it look like in the application?

I apologize ahead of time if this is confusing. Please ask questions and I will try to clear it up. I'm using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take different approach. I would add a column consecutive_wins into your User model (negative numbers could represent consecutive losses if you need that as well).

**EDIT: if you really need to query it...**

Two queries:

1. select the newest victory and newest loose for given user (could be done in one query, in SQL `SELECT max(created_at) AS newest, win_loss FROM games GROUP BY win_loss` (I can't recall how to do grouping functions in Rails right now but you should get the idea)
2. and then, regarding the result of query (1):

   1. if both newest win and newest lose are found, count the games with condition that `created_at > newest_win AND created_at > newest_lose`
   2. if only newest win or lose found, user was always wining or always loosing, just count the number of his games
   3. in other case there were no games

I recommend adding the column to user model, it will be better when you need to display the whole table of gamers and their consecutive wins/loses.

Comment: Say I add the consecutive wins/losses to my User model. How would you go about finding it that way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question... What do you want to find?

Comment: Well, even if I add the column consecutive_wins to my User model, I still need to find the consecutive wins and input it into the table. How would you suggest doing that?

Comment: You don't need to. Any time the user finishes his game, you are updating this column according to its previous value. If he wins and the consecutive_wins_loses is positive, you are increasing its value by one. If he wins and the consecutive_wins_loses is negative or equal to zero, you are setting it to -1. For loses, you do similar thing.